# Understanding Linq To Xml - Descendants return no results

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I'm a completly New to Linq2XML as I code to much lines to perform simple things, and in a simple project I wanted to give it a try...

I'm with this for 2 hours and nothing I do get's it right :(

I'm really, really thinking to go back to **XmlNode-code-alike**

**The Task:**

- I send a SOAP Action to an ASMX service and I get the response as XML
- I Parse the XML into a XDocument object
- I try to get a list of nodes ... err! Problem!

as you can see from this [screenshot](http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2010-02-26_0038.png)

[alt text http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2010-02-26_0038.png](http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2010-02-26_0038.png)

my **XDocument** has a Node called **TransactionInformationType** witch is a Sequence, and I simple want to get all and retrieve the only 2 variables that I need (you can see the code commented) just below **select c;**

in the **Watch** window you can see that

```
doc.Descendants("TransactionInformationType")
```

returns nothing at all, and seeing by the content of the XDocument in the Text Visualizer, it does exist!

Anyone care to explain and help me passing this HUGE wall?

Thank you!

---

**Added**

> [XDocument content](http://pastebin.com/iNGJJfsV)

---

**Answer**

the Response XML has

> `<gettransactionlistResponse xmlns="https://ssl.ditonlinebetalingssystem.dk/remote/payment">`

and I must use this as Namespace!

turns out that, to **retrieve values**, I do need to **use the XNamespace as well**, so the final code looks like this:

```
// Parse XML
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(strResponse);
XNamespace ns = "https://ssl.ditonlinebetalingssystem.dk/remote/payment";

var trans = from item in doc.Descendants(ns + "TransactionInformationType")
            select new TransactionInformationType
            {
                capturedamount = Convert.ToInt32(item.Element(ns + "capturedamount").Value),
                orderid = item.Element(ns + "cardtypeid").Value
            };
```

---

**Thank you all** for the help!

Comment: Could you please post the header of the XML up to the element you are looking for. There may be a namespace issue here.

Comment: done! add it to pasteBin as it's big (even if I show only 2 Transactions) :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xml.Linq: Descendants() returns nothing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7503276/xml-linq-descendants-returns-nothing)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
var result = doc.Descendants("TransactionInformationType");
```

selects all descendants in the XDocument that have element name `"TransactionInformationType"` and are in the empty namespace. 
From you screenshot it seems the element you're trying to select is in the namespace `"https://ssl.ditonlinebetalingssystem.dk/remote/payment"` though. 
You need to specify that explicitly:

```
XNamespace ns = "https://ssl.ditonlinebetalingssystem.dk/remote/payment";
                                              ↑↑                      ↑
var result = doc.Descendants(ns + "TransactionInformationType");
```

Comment: Just added XDocument content to my answer. If I use `"https://ssl.ditonlinebetalingsystem.dk/remote/payment/"` as XNamespace, I get the same behavior ... in other words, still nothing :(

Comment: @balexandre: There is no `/` after `payment` in your example, and an `s` is missing. Make sure you're using the exact same namespace in your C# as found in the XML example.

Comment: with or without, result is the same ): http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2010-02-26_0136.png

Comment: Just wrote a quick sample, seems to work. http://pastebin.org/97518
Something must be different on your end if it doesn't.

Answer (score 12):

This should solve you isssue (replace the namespace with the right URL):

```
XNamespace ns = "https://ssl.ditonline...";
doc.Descendants(ns + "TransactionInformationType");
```