# LINQ to XML - why is Elements always null

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

im having trouble getting elements from my XML. I cannot get the Vehicles or Vehicle elements from my XML, it always returns null.

Can any one see where im going wrong?

Here is my code...

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestDeleteVehicleFromXMLFile()
    {
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(base._TestXPathXMLFile, FileMode.Open))
        {
            try
            {
                XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(stream);
                var q = from RootNode in xDoc.Descendants("VehicleCache")

                    select new
                    {
                        // Vehicles & VehiclesList is always null
                        Vehicles = RootNode.Elements(XName.Get("Vehicle")).ToList(),
                        VehiclesList = RootNode.Elements(XName.Get("Vehicles")).ToList(),
                        SelfNode = RootNode.DescendantNodesAndSelf().ToList(),
                        DescendantNodes = RootNode.DescendantNodes().ToList()
                    };

                // used to see what is in item
                foreach (var item in q)
                {
                    int i = 0;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception E)
            {
                Assert.Fail(E.Message);
            }
        }
    }


<VehicleCache>
<Vehicles xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.myURL.co.uk">
    <Vehicle>
      <CapCode>41653</CapCode>
      <TrueCap i:nil="true" />
      <VehicleID>365789</VehicleID>
      <ViperVehicleID i:nil="true" />
      <BodyTypeID>5</BodyTypeID>
    </Vehicle>
    <Vehicle>
      <CapCode>42565</CapCode>
      <TrueCap i:nil="true" />
      <VehicleID>365845</VehicleID>
      <ViperVehicleID i:nil="true" />
      <BodyTypeID>2</BodyTypeID>
    </Vehicle>
</Vehicles>
```

Comment: Do you have a namespace inside?

Comment: thanks for the answers - the question i have is, when i used to use Xpath all those years ago, i could get a node without having to know the ns, do you always needs to know the namespace to get an element using LINQ to XML ?

Comment: It is possible. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145659/ignore-namespaces-in-linq-to-xml

Comment: @Truegilly, check the edited answer as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xml.Linq: Descendants() returns nothing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7503276/xml-linq-descendants-returns-nothing)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Define XNamespace

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.myURL.co.uk";
```

Use that:

```
Vehicles = RootNode.Elements(XName.Get(ns + "Vehicle")).ToList(),
```

Or if you want to avoid using Namespace then try:

```
var result = xDoc.Descendants().Where(r => r.Name.LocalName == "VehicleCache");
```

Answer (score 3):

you need to include your namespace.

```
XNamespace Snmp = "http://www.myURL.co.uk";
```

for root descendants also you need to include namespace.

```
var q = from RootNode in xDoc.Descendants(Snmp +"VehicleCache")
```

like this

```
Vehicles = RootNode.Elements(XName.Get(Snmp + "Vehicle")).ToList()//snmp is the namespace
```